# Error: "Undefined symbol" when trying to import pyarrow/feather

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, pyarrow, feather

I installed `feather` via

```
conda install feather-format -c conda-forge
```

In the process, `pyarrow` and possibly more packages were installed by conda.

When trying to do `import feather`, I get the following error message:

```
ImportError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-1d29cbb85491> in <module>
----> 1 import feather

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/feather/__init__.py in <module>
15 # flake8: noqa
16
---> 17 from pyarrow.feather import (read_feather as read_dataframe, # noqa
18 write_feather as write_dataframe,
19 FeatherError)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyarrow/__init__.py in <module>
52
53
---> 54 from pyarrow.lib import cpu_count, set_cpu_count
55 from pyarrow.lib import (null, bool_,
56 int8, int16, int32, int64,

ImportError: /home/MyUserName/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyarrow/lib.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK5arrow6Status8ToStringB5cxx11Ev
```

I am using Ubuntu 20.04, and this is my Python 3.7.7 installed via Anaconda.

Comment: How have you installed `pyarrow` and `arrow-cpp` and in which version?

Comment: @UweL.Korn yes, bot `pyarrow` and `arrow-cpp` are version 0.11.1. I think `boost` and `boost-cpp` were also installed, in version 1.68.0

Comment: Oh, that's quite an ancient version of `pyarrow`, please update to a more recent one.

Answer (score 1):

You can conda uninstall pyarrow and install it with pip tool, it works on my environment which raise the same exception.